# Can't find image on DockerHub

Tags: docker

In my docker file, I have the first line
`FROM elezar/caffe:cpu`
it runs perfectly, 
but when I search `elezar/caffe:cpu` on 
`https://hub.docker.com/`
Nothing is shown, what is the reason?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/layers/elezar/caffe/cpu/images/sha256-d2fc0a3e942290fdf275cc072f329557b1ba1b0210436c42cd11481d7b4b318c?context=explore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always search the image without tag on Dockerhub. [Here](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=elezar%2Fcaffe&type=image) is the search results when done without tag. Here is the image [repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/elezar/caffe) that you are looking for. You can find the tags in [Tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/elezar/caffe/tags) tab at the repo page.